# RoutingError (cannot load Java class hello.MyFirstJavaProgram)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am using jruby for the first time and i am trying to load a jar file which later on i will try to send parameters in and run some stuff.

I used a tutorial to write sample hello world java program using the code below

```
package test_pack;

public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

    public static void main(String []args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

i place the `helloworld.java` file inside a `test_pack` folder and i then packed it using a command to produce a .jar file.

i placed the .jar file into the `lib` directory of rails, and used the following code to call it

```
class WebhookController < ApplicationController

  require "java"
  require "hello.jar"
  java_import "hello.MyFirstJavaProgram"
  Java::test_pack::MyFirstJavaProgram.main()


  def check

  end


end
```

but it gives me the error

> cannot load Java class hello.MyFirstJavaProgram

obviously my path is wrong but i do not know how to fix it, any clues welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java_import "test_pack.MyFirstJavaProgram"
```

should do the trick.

PS. Also, in java world, you should name your file the same as your class name. In your case your filename should be `MyFirstJavaProgram.java`, not `helloworld.java`.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the notes but unfortunately i still get the same error. I also went and renamed the java file. Is there something else i can try??

Comment: Did you recompiled and repackaged your jar file and restarted the rails server?

Comment: by recompiled what do you mean? - repackaged the jar file and restarted the server yes . PS i am super new to java as well

Comment: EDIT: i took the compile thing into account, and it seems i had to also use the javac command repack with just the .class file and then replace it in rails,restart server and now the class is found but i get this error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` when calling `main()` any clue on that?

Comment: As you can see, the `main(String []args)` method is expecting an array of `String` arguments. So, you have to pass an empty array to it.